# Prove or find a counterexample. If $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $f \vert_Z$ is bounded, then $f$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

In Lebl's Real Analysis, there is a question:
True/False, prove or find a counterexample. If $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that
$f \vert_Z$  is bounded, then $f$ is bounded.
I believe this is wrong and I have found a function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\sin({\frac{1}{x}})$
How would one go about proving this is UNBOUNDED in the real numbers. I believe I can restrict the domain to $(0,1]$ too. 
Thanks :)

Comment: To prove it is unbounded, show that for every $M\gt 0$ there exists a value of $x$ such that $|f(x)| \gt M$.

Comment: Your function is not defined at $x=0$, and would not be continuous there if it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function $f: \Bbb R \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ defined by

$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            2(m+1)(x-m) & \quad m \leq x < m + \frac 1 2,\ m \in \Bbb N \cup \{0 \} \\
            -2(m+1) (x-m-1) & \quad m + \frac 1 2 \leq x < m+1,\ m \in \Bbb N \cup \{0 \} \\
             -2m (x+m) & \quad -m \leq x < -m + \frac 1 2,\ m \in \Bbb N \\
              2m (x+m-1) & \quad - m + \frac 1 2 \leq x < -m+1,\ m \in \Bbb N
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  find a function whose graph looks something like this.

[image]